# What do I do with this monkey I have found?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

I keep coming across a monkey when I am wandering in the forest/mountains or down by the lake.

I can pick him up, but that seems to annoy him.

Does he have a purpose? He seems out of place, unlike the boars and bears and such that I have seen.

What can I do with the monkey? Does he have a purpose?

Comment: I've ran into several monkeys.  They seem to be wildlife, just like the other creatures.  They all seem to run from me, currently.

Comment: Can I make the wildlife my friends?

Comment: The tutorial mentioned something along those lines, about trying to give them fodder or something.

Comment: I missed that. Gonna try that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can feed them, pick them up, and talk with them, eventually befriending them.

When you become really good friends with the certain wild animals, entering their area will trigger a gift event.

The wild animal family will give you 10 of a certain item based on the animal family you befriend. By befriending a wild animal of a particular color, you might unlock another different colored one of the same family (which you can also befriend) or something else....

Here is an updated list of wild animal likes and gifts translated from this [wiki](http://i-love-game.com/bokumono-hajimari/animal/yasei.php).

**Likes/Gifts** (wild animal are available all year unless otherwise noted, gifts are in sets of 10, unless otherwise noted):

- **Duck** (Spring/Summer) (Sunny) (River) (Morning to Midnight)

  > **Likes:**  All vegetables (except onions and spinach), all fruits, soybeans, wheat, rice
  >
  > **Gives:** Basil
- **Duck (Alternate)** (Winter/Fall) (Sunny) (River/Sakura Land) (Morning to Midnight)

  > **Likes:**  All vegetables (except onions and spinach), all fruits
  >
  > **Notes:** Unlocked by befriending Duck
  >
  > **Gives:** White Rose
- **Brown Boar** (Snow/Sunny) (River/Summit/Forest) (Morning to Evening)

  > **Likes:** Eggs, golden eggs, Silkie eggs, mushrooms, king oyster mushrooms, shiitake, pineapple, apple, kiwi, orange, peach, watermelon, banana, strawberry, corn, radish, cabbage, potato, carrot, tomato, potato, turnip
  >
  > **Gives:** Pink Rose
- **Black Boar** (Snow/Sunny) (River/Forest) (Morning to Evening)

  > **Likes:** Same as Brown Boar, except Coral Mushrooms instead of Silkie eggs.
  >
  > **Notes:** Unlocked by befriending the Brown Boar.
  >
  > **Gives:** Nadeshiko
- **Black Rabbit** (Spring to Fall) (Sunny) (River) (Morning/Noon to Evening)

  > **Likes:** Fodder, grapes, cherries, pineapple, apple, banana, strawberry, corn, broccoli, cabbage, pumpkin, cabbage, potato, carrot, tomato, potato, turnip
  >
  > **Gives:** Tulip
- **White Rabbit** (Fall/Winter) (Snow) (Summit) (Noon to Evening/Midnight to Morning)

  > **Likes:** Same as (Black) Rabbit.
  >
  > **Notes:** Unlocked by befriending the Black Rabbit
  >
  > **Gives:** Lavender
- **Brown/White Ermine** (Sunny) (River, Summit, Forest, Snow Land [White]) (Day)

  > **Likes:** Eggs, golden eggs, Silkie eggs
  >
  > **Notes:** White Ermines are only available in Snow Land
  >
  > **Gives:** Chamomile (Brown), Margaret (White)
- **Yellow Fox** (Spring/Summer) (Snow/Sunny) (Forest) (Noon to Evening, Midnight to Morning)

  > **Likes:** Eggs, golden eggs, Silkie eggs, All mushrooms (except shiitake), all vegetables (except onion and spinach)
  >
  > **Gives:** Rosemary
- **Silver Fox** (Fall/Winter) (Snow/Sunny) (Forest) (Noon to Evening, Morning)

  > **Likes:** Same as Yellow Fox
  >
  > **Notes:** Unlocked by befriending Yellow Fox
  >
  > **Gives:** Red Rose
- **Brown Bear** (Spring to Fall) (Sunny) (River/Summit/Forest) (Morning to evening)

  > **Likes:** Honey, all vegetables (except spinach and onion)
  >
  > **Gives:** Sage
- **Black Bear** (Spring to Fall) (Sunny) (River/Forest) (Morning to evening)

  > **Likes:** Same as Brown Bear, but also salmon and alcohol
  >
  > **Notes:** Unlocked by befriending Brown Raccoon
  >
  > **Gives:** Hydrangea
- **Brown/Gold Monkey** (Spring/Summer) (Rain/Sunny) (Forest/Summit/River/Southern Island/Ruins) (Morning to evening)

  > **Likes:** All vegetables (except spinach), all fruit, lotus root, wasabi, soybeans, all mushrooms, all cheese, eggs, golden eggs, Silkie eggs
  >
  > **Notes:** Gold Monkeys are unique to the Ruins
  >
  > **Gives:** Bayleaf (Brown), Gerbera (Gold)
- **Brown/Olive Sparrow** (Sunny/Snow/Rain) (Summit, River, Forest, Sakura Land) (Morning to evening)

  > **Likes:** Corn, wheat, rice, soybeans
  >
  > **Notes:** Olive sparrows are only available in Sakura Land during the day
  >
  > **Gives:** Mint (Brown), Thyme (Olive)
- **Brown Raccoon** (Rain/Sunny) (River/Summit) (Day)

  > **Likes:** All vegetables (except spinach), all fruit, eggs, golden eggs, Silkie eggs
  >
  > **Gives:** Bergamot
- **Dark Brown Raccoon** (Spring/Summer) (Sunny) (River) (Evening to morning)

  > **Likes:** Same as Brown Raccoon
  >
  > **Notes:** Unlocked by befriending Brown Raccoon
  >
  > **Gives:** Gentian
- **Panda** (Sunny) (Forest) (Night to Morning)

  > **Likes:** Bamboo, wheat, rice, grapes, banana, strawberry, corn, cabbage, potato, carrot, tomato, potato, turnip
  >
  > **Notes:** Wild animals that inhabit the River/Summit/Forest might also appear
  >
  > **Gives:** Sunflower
- **Turtle** (Southern Island only) (Day)

  > **Likes:** All fish
  >
  > **Notes:** Once you become friend it can take you to the Southern Island (unlocks area so you don't have to use the Travel Agency)
  >
  > **Gives:** Aloe
- **Yeti** (Snow Land only) (Day)

  > **Likes:** All vegetables (except spinach), all fruit, all fish
  >
  > **Personal Note:** Yetis are cool
  >
  > **Gives:** Snow Drop
- **Polar Bear** (Snow Land) (Day)

  > **Likes:** All fruit, all fish
  >
  > **Gives:** Blue Rose
- **Peacock** (Ancient Ruins only) (Daytime)

  > **Likes:** Soybean, wheat, rice, all vegetables (except spinach)
  >
  > **Gives:** Pink Diamond (x1)

Comment: I suspect the Pink Diamond is much more valuable than the rest.

Comment: How do I become their friend?

Comment: @fbueckert the pink diamond's for the baby bed